# Matching all occurrences regex

Tags: python, regex

I have this string `hellohatto`

If I have this re: `h.{1,20}o`

it will match only the whole word `hellohatto` but I want `hello`, `hatto` and `hellohatto`.

Could you just guide me in the right direction? What am I missing?

**Edit**

I'm sorry I didn't explain better. I just want to find a regular expression to find all the matches that start with `h` and end with `o` from 1 to max 20 characters between them. In my example this should give me 3 matches:

"`hello`", "`hatto`" and "`hellohatto`".

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Unclear what you need. Could you please explain what output you need and what not? Why not hellohatto? how do you expect regex to know that hatto is other word?

Comment: @SMA What do you mean, "why not hellohatto"? hellohatto is on the list of wanted results.

Comment: @melpomene let OP answer it and clarify what he wants. It's as per what i understand and hence i said its unclear what OP needs

Comment: @SMA What is unclear about "*I want "hello", "hatto" and "hellohatto"*"?

Comment: @melpomene I'm using python

Comment: How about `re.findall`

Comment: @HyperNeutrino finds "hellohatto" only

Comment: You cannot match several substrings starting at the same location with regex. Generate all substrings from the string and test them against the regex. Collect those that matched.

Comment: @AleJuliet Please check my updated solution.

Comment: What about `hellohattohinno`? Do you want all these matches: `hatto`, `hello`, `hinno`, `hattohello`, `hellohinno` and `hellohattohinno`? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use find all to get all the strings starting and ending with specific letters but you cannot extend the ending ignoring one.

Eg.

```
import re

x = "helasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfdlohatto"
y = "hellohatto"
x1 = re.findall(r"h\w{0,20}?o",x)
x2 = re.findall(r"h\w{0,20}?o",y)

['hatto'] #x1
['hello', 'hatto'] #x2
```

Comment: thanks. I was just confused about using the lazy quantifier.

Comment: @AleJuliet:  This doesn't match the whole word `hellohatto` as requested.

Comment: If you have the code for that you will definitely get my vote. This is all I could think sorry

Answer (score 0):

As you have updated and edit your question so here is my updated answer for your problem which match all the words from 0,20 start with "h" and end with "o"

```
import re

pattern = r'(?=(\bh\w*o\b))(h\w*?o)?(h\w*?o)?(h\w*?o)?(h\w*?o)?(h\w*?o)?(h\w*?o)?'
string_match = ["hellohatto"]
new_list=[]
for iter_1 in string_match:

    match = re.findall(pattern, iter_1,re.M)
    for i in match:
        print([final_match for final_match in i if final_match])
```

successfully tried on many words check live :

https://regex101.com/r/7X3KRr/9

> Old solutions :

You could also try this with group capturing method :

```
import re

pattern = r'(\w{5})(\w+)'
string_match = "hellohatto"

match = re.search(pattern, string_match)

print("first match = {} \n second match = {} \n third match = {}".format(match.group(0),match.group(1),match.group(2)))
```

different regex pattern :

```
import re

pattern = r'(h[ell | att]+o)(h[ell | att]+o)'
string_match = "hellohatto"

match = re.search(pattern, string_match)

print(match.group(0),match.group(1),match.group(2))
```

But if you want only two words separate then this match perfect :

```
  import re

pattern = r'(h[ell | att]+o)'
string_match = "hellohatto"

match = re.findall(pattern, string_match)

for i in match:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Did you read the question? They want to match words that begin with "h", end with "o" with from 1 up to 20 characters inbetween.

Comment: @Toto when i read they didn't explain that thing , they edited the question later.

Comment: @Toto i have updated my solution according to their new edited problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = "hellohatto"
ans = re.findall(r"h.*?o",y) + (re.findall(r"h.*o", y))
print(ans)
```

output:
['hello', 'hatto', 'hellohatto']

Comment: You can combine the greedy and non-greedy search outputs.